# What happens if only one runner reaches base on a double steal?

Tags: baseball

There are two outs, with men on first and third. The one man leaves first and gets caught in a rundown. The other man steals home as a result. The first man gets tagged out, but not before the other run reaches home.

Is the run counted or not, since the one runner reached home first? That is, BEFORE the out? (In the actual play I'm thinking of, Pittsburgh vs. Atlanta, both men reached.)

Do I assume correctly if the man on first made the second (instead of third) out, that the run is counted?

Comment: @Joe. No. My question is does a run count if it is made BEFORE an unforced out?

Comment: Sure, and the answer to your question is exactly the same as in the linked question.  To the point the same rule is quoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a runner scores before the third out is made on a play such as you describe, the run counts. The runner on first stealing second is not considered a force play, therefore, the run counts.

Rule 5.08(a) states:

> One run shall be scored each time a runner legally advances to
>   and touches first, second, third and home base before three men
>   are put out to end the inning.
>
> EXCEPTION: A run is not scored if the runner
>   advances to home base during a play in which the third
>   out is made (1) by the batter-runner before he touches
>   first base; (2) by any runner being forced out; or (3) by
>   a preceding runner who is declared out because he
>   failed to touch one of the bases.

The scenario described follows the rule, and does not fall into any of the three exceptions.

Please also note that the rules were reorganized for the 2015 season, so some rules are in different places in the book.